# Hide the keyboard (blur) when clicking out of a textField inside a tableView in Titanium

Tags: keyboard, titanium, tableview, textfield, blur

I'm trying to get a table in Titanium where each row has a static text and a textField where I can input something.

So I go and create a row where it's left part is the static text and the right part it's my input text field.
Just a small problem, I can't hide the keyboard by clicking outside of it.

If it was a normal textField outside a table I would just use the blur method, but in this case I can't get that to work.

This is my code so far:
Any idea on how this works and if the solution is valid for both iOS and Android?

```
var winAddObjectView = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var tableAddObjectData = [
    {title:'name', hintText:'item name (optional)'},
    {title:'track no.', hintText:'object tracking code'}
];

var tableAddObjectRowData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tableAddObjectData.length; i++) {
    var title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:tableAddObjectData[i].title,
        textAlign:"right",
        left:"20",
        height:'auto',
        width:'68',
        color:'#526691',
        font:{fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold'},
    });
    var textField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        hintText:tableAddObjectData[i].hintText,
        textAlign:"left",
        left:"96",
        height:'auto',
        width:'184',
        color:'#4C4C4C',
        font:{fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold'},
    });

    winAddObjectView.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        textField.blur();
    });

    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:"45",
    });

    row.add(title);
    row.add(textField);
    tableAddObjectRowData.push(row);
}

var tableAddObjectView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    headerTitle:'Enter Tracking Information',
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    data:tableAddObjectRowData,
});

winAddObjectView.add(tableAddObjectView)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a few changes in your code. Please try this

```
var tableAddObjectRowData = [];
var textFields = [];              //Created an array of textFields
for (var i = 0; i < tableAddObjectData.length; i++) {
    var title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:tableAddObjectData[i].title,
        textAlign:"right",
        left:"20",
        height:'auto',
        width:'68',
        color:'#526691',
        font:{fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold'},
    });
    textFields[i] = Ti.UI.createTextField({            //Creating the textField
        hintText:tableAddObjectData[i].hintText,
        textAlign:"left",
        left:"96",
        height:'auto',
        width:'184',
        color:'#4C4C4C',
        font:{fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold'},
    });

    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:"45",
    });

    row.add(title);
    row.add(textFields[i]);
    tableAddObjectRowData.push(row);
}

var tableAddObjectView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    headerTitle:'Enter Tracking Information',
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    data:tableAddObjectRowData,
    height : (tableAddObjectRowData.length * 45) + 60     //Added the height property for the tableView
});

winAddObjectView.addEventListener("click", hideSoftKeyboard);  //added event listener to the window, moved this to out of the loop

function hideSoftKeyboard(){                  //Added function to hide the keyboard
    for(var i=0; i<textFields.length; i++){
        textFields[i].blur();             //Hiding each keyboards
    }
}
winAddObjectView.add(tableAddObjectView);
```

**Explanation**

1. `winAddObjectView.addEventListener("click", function(e){
       textField.blur();
   });`
   The above code segment in your program didn't worked because the `click` event for the window was not firing **due to the height of tableView, the window was hidden and your clicks were firing on the tableView**. You can see the difference if you set the `backgroundColor` property for your tableView. So I adjusted the height of the tableView and hence the click fired in the window and the keyboard has gone.
2. Creation of textField array : You can do the same without creating the textField array and inside the `for loop` you can create the textField as `var textField = Ti.UI.createTextField();`. But if you do so, you cannot hide keayboard all the times, since event will be fired for the last textField only. Hence I created the textField array
3. For `Android` you can also use [Ti.UI.android.hideSoftKeybaord()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Android-method-hideSoftKeyboard) method. For that just change the `hideSoftkeyboard()` method in our code as follows

   ```
   function hideSoftKeyboard(){                  //Added function to hide the keyboard
       if(Ti.Platform.osname === 'android'){
            Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard();
       } else {
            for(var i=0; i<textFields.length; i++){
                 textFields[i].blur();             //Hiding each keayboards
            }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Anand. This was a fantastic explanation! Just one small detail. With your code, the table shows up in the middle of the screen this way and gets hidden by the keyboard. So I changed `height : (tableAddObjectRowData.length * 45) + 60` to `height : ((textFields.length + 1) * 45),
 top : "0",` It now works and dismisses the keyboard if I click beneath the table (but not on the title for instance). Do you think this is a good solution or propose something different? I still don't understand why I must put the height of the table for the blur to work tough.

Comment: @jbssm: As I explained in the point 1, 'the window was hidden by the tableView' in your code so we had to adjust the height of the tableView. With my code, the keyboard is blurred only when you click on the window. Please try to set different backgroundColor property for the window and the tableView in your code before and after setting the tableView height, you can easily understand it...

Comment: Thank you, the backgroundColor trick was very useful, I now understand what is going on.

Comment: @jbssm: Thanks for your comment. It was a simple mistake. Usually we may miss it and will lose hours behind such simple issues :D